# MDC-Web Typography: Font Customization

Tags: material-components, material-components-web

Is the [MDC typography](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-typography) specific to the Roboto font, or can we implement with other Google fonts and if so, is the recommended way simply to apply the `font-family` CSS to `body`?

Lastly, it appears that [all header elements are tied to the `<h1>` element](https://material-components-web.appspot.com/typography.html) which seems to break the semantic nature of HTML5, i.e. `h1` normally has higher significance than `h5`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MDC-Web is a customizable library, and given the fact that [Google doesn't prohibit using your brand styles along with Material Design framework](https://design.google/library/expressing-brand-material/), you're free to use any font, not just "Roboto".

If you're using CSS-only approach, adding `font-family` to `body` is not enough: MDC-Web applies default typography styles (including `font-family`) to different components (e.g., `mdc-button`, `mdc-list`, `mdc-card`) and typography classes, and they still will have “Roboto” font applied. So, if you’re going to use such MDC-Web components and classes, you need to manually specify `font-family` for each of them:

```
.mdc-button {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.mdc-list {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.mdc-card__supporting-text {
  font-family: “Open Sans”, sans-serif;
}
```

But this might be tedious, so the recommended way to generate MDC-Web styling is to use Sass. Specifically, you need to override [MDC-Web’s typography variable](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/packages/mdc-typography/_variables.scss) in your `.scss` file before importing the component:

```
$mdc-typography-font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;

@import "@material/typography/mdc-typography";
```

Another method [is described](https://m2.material.io/develop/web/guides/typography) in the MDCv2 developer documentation:

```scss
@use "@material/typography" with (
  $font-family: unquote("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
);
```

This method leverages Sass module variables.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use SASS, you can do some basic customisation by setting variables in your css. For example:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:200,300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/site.css" />
```

`site.css`

```css
:root {
    --mdc-typography-font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
    font-family: var(--mdc-typography-font-family);
}
```

You can also override the default theme colours using variables like this:

```css
--mdc-theme-primary: #0d46a0;
```

More info can be found here: https://material.io/develop/web/docs/theming

Comment: Thoughts on using this approach with a variable font in addition to a fallback?

Comment: Sure, should work: `--mdc-typography-font-family: var(--site-font), 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;`